# Mt85 bobcat mini tractor

Tags: electrical, diesel

So the customer replaced the battery because of machine wouldn’t turn on. Few days later the customer needs to jumpstart the battery because it’s not turning on again, but only turns on when it’s jumpstarted. I came to check it out and my tester indicated a bad battery so I put a new battery in it and I started reading over 15 amperage on the ground side of the battery. I made a tool with an inline resettable fuse and a switch to mostly prevent damage to other components due to this overcurrent. I placed this tool in series from the negative battery post to the negative battery cable. So I disconnected everything leaving the only the starter and battery within the circuit. I even disconnected the switch and probed the the s terminal wire with so I can put direct power through it via a power probe. With all fuses, relays and connectors removed my fuse still blows off when I try to start it through either the power probe or the switch (when I momentarily plug it in). The grounds are all continuous to the frame. I noticed that my s wire going to the s terminal on the starter was reading ground. That circuit has a diode that flows into the glow plug circuit and that diode reads OL on both sides when that s wire is connected to the s terminal. I disconnected that wire from the s terminal and my diode was reading correctly when testing it. The short is only happening when that s wire is energized. I removed the harness and replaced every single diode and made sure every wire was continuous to their respective ends and not shorted into each other. I literally traced every single wire on the schematics so I made certain the harness was in working condition.

I replaced the alternator less than a month ago due to charging issues which was resolved after replacing it. I’ll provide the schematics. Any insight? Lol. I’ll stop by tmr to directly test the starter.  [image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0HK3.png)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Five amps *what*? Draw? CCA? Not sure what you're asking?

Comment: Hello. I just updated the post.

Comment: When you energise the starter, there will possibly be around 100A flowing through the negative battery cable, so unless you have installed a very large fuse, it will blow every time you run the starter.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "diode reads OL on both sides when that s wire is connected to the s terminal"?  How are you doing this test?

Comment: Are you saying that 15A is being drawn from the battery with everything turned off? If so, have you tried pulling fuses to identify which circuit is drawing the current?  I would also disconnect the alternator to see if that is drawing the current, since it is likely the only component permanently connected to the battery without a fuse.

Comment: I thought that there was to be absolutely no current on the frame ground to the battery

Comment: But if there’s suppose to be current then I know what’s going on. Thank you!

Comment: Presuming this is a diesel engine requiring glow plugs to preheat the combustion chambers in cold temperatures prior to startup, the glow plug fuse before the 87a relay is rated for 35 amps. Are glow plugs pulling the 15 amps? Does this engine use a manually switched glow plug or is it automatic and tied to the engine coolant temperature sensor?

Comment: They’re manually switched. I’ve figured my hydraulic fan shorting out. The pin on the relay for the fan is melted.